# Recoverability enabled VS extending retention by 14 days with Recoverability disabled

Tags: azure-data-explorer

What is the difference between setting N days of retention policy with Recoverability Enabled Vs setting N+14 days of retention policy with Recoverability disabled. In case of recoverability enabled , I guess the data older than N days is kept in cold storage and so the cost is lower? I am trying to assess pros and cons of both the approaches. Because logically both would mean the same thing but trying to understand cost implications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no cost difference, they are the same since the retention policy controls the time that the data is kept in blob storage and in both options the data is kept in blob storage for the same duration.

The difference is that when the retention is 14d longer but with recoverability disabled the data is available for query for additional 14d compared with the original retention but with recoverability enabled.

Comment: Yes I got that -- I mean if there is no cost difference, it sounds like N+14 sounds like a better approach, if we are paying for it anyways why not have an option to be able to query that too? It's also not the case that it's going to some cold storage and saving storage cost -- everything is the same but only access is removed. Seems like N+14 is a better approach. I am trying to think of a reason why someone will prefer the other option over N+14 but cant find any.

Comment: Some people prefer to have a safety zone that can only be accessed in case of emergency than have no safety but the data exposed for longer period. I think that both views are valid and legitimate.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the docs here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/retentionpolicy

Recoverability period of 14 days allows you to "undo" accident drop of the data (by 
creating a support ticket). The data that is dropped is kept in storage for additional 14 days - so it can increase storage costs.